# How to separate characters in text file with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I am making a python program, and I want to be able to read A Text file, I can already do that but I want to get certain information out of it. For Example my Text File would look like this:

```
Red Banana = R LL R H SKG LGHE
Green Chicken = AH HGKE HGKELG GHEk
Cardbored Box = GHEHE HKEGLS GHEK
Awesome Man = G E GHLEKGH HEKG GEHLG
```

I want to sperate the left column from the right column by the equal sign. So I would take "Red Banana" as a string and make "R LL R H SKG LGHE" another string. It would be a bonus if I could put all of the left column in a list. Thank You very Much.

Comment: You want the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method. hint: and use it like `split('=')`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you consider using any of the [string methods](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)?

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what your difficulty is, what you expected, what you got, and any traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().split('\n')
left = [line.split('=')[0].strip() for line in lines]
right = [line.split('=')[1].strip() for line in lines]
print(left)
print(right)
```

Output is

```
['Red Banana', 'Green Chicken', 'Cardbored Box', 'Awesome Man']
['R LL R H SKG LGHE', 'AH HGKE HGKELG GHEk', 'GHEHE HKEGLS GHEK', 'G E GHLEKGH HEKG GEHLG']
```

Answer (score 1):

ComplicatedPhenomenon already has it sorted, but just for the bonus points - to get the left side of the column into a list just replace the "1" in the last line with a "0", ie:

```py
with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().split('\n')
print([line.split('=')[0].strip() for line in lines])
```